# Passing an array using protocols/delegates

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have tried over and over to get this to work, but to no avail. I am trying to pass an array from a SendingVC to a ReceivingVC and display the content of that array in two labels.

SendingVC Code:

```
import UIKit

protocol SenderVCDelegate {
    func passArrayData(data: [String])
}

class SendingVC: UIViewController {

    // DELEGATE
    var delegate: SenderVCDelegate?

    var carDetails: [String]? = ["BMW", "X5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToFirst(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        //
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if (carDetails?.isEmpty)! {
            return false
        } else {
            if let delegate = delegate, let data = carDetails {
                delegate.passArrayData(data: data)
                print("from inside segue: \(data)")
            }

            return true
        }
    }
}
```

ReceivingVC Code

```
import UIKit

class ReceivingVC: UIViewController, SenderVCDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl01: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl02: UILabel!

    var incomingCarDetails: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("from inside viewLoad: \(incomingCarDetails)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if let sendingVC: SendingVC = segue.destination as? SendingVC {
            sendingVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func passArrayData(data: [String]) {
        incomingCarDetails = data

        populateLabels(array: incomingCarDetails)
    }

    func populateLabels(array: [String]) {
        for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                lbl01.text = value
            case 1:
                lbl02.text = value
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a delegate for this. You simply set the property in `preparaForSegue`

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to use a delegate for this.

Comment: Ok, you still need to set the delegate in `prepareForSegue`, but it really makes no sense.  You are going to set a property on an instance of `ReceivingVC` that enables it to call a function on `SendingVC` to get an array returned from `SendingVC`; why not just set the array property on `ReceivingVC` and be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have confusion around the role of a delegate and where it should be implemented.  You don't need to use a delegate to pass data from `SendingVC` to `RecevingVC`, you can simply set the property on the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue`;

```
class SendingVC: UIViewController {

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ReceivingVC {
            destVC.incomingCarDetails = self.carDetails
        }
    }
}
```

If you *do* want to use a delegate, then you will set the `SendingVC` instance as the delegate of your `ReceivingVC` in `prepareForSegue` and change your protocol so that the delegate method returns data, rather than accepts data:

```
protocol SenderVCDelegate {
    func passArrayData() -> [String]
}
```

Then, you can implement the delegate method and set the delegate in `prepareForSegue`

```
class SendingVC: UIViewController, SenderVCDelegate {

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ReceivingVC {
            destVC.senderDelegate = self
        }
    }

    func passArrayData() -> [String] {
        return self.carDetails
    }
}
```

In `ReceivingVC` you can call the delegate method in `viewWillAppear`

```
class ReceivingVC: UIViewController {

    var incomingCarDetails = [String]()
    var senderDelegate: SenderVCDelegate?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let incomingDetails = self.senderDelegate?.passArrayData() {
            self.incomingCarDetails = incomingDetails
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a whole lot more work and no benefit.  A delegation pattern is typically used where you want to send data *back* and where the function call will happen at an unpredictable time, such as in response to a network operation completing or a user interaction.